# Does $f = \frac{(2x+\sin x)\arctan x}{x^2}\;$ have a minimum on $(0,\infty)$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

Let $f = \frac{(2x+\sin x)\arctan x}{x^2}$

Does $f$ have a minimum on the interval $(0,\infty)?$

---

I tried to calculate the limit at the edges, I got:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) = 0$$
$$\lim_{x \to 0}f(x) = 2$$

Here I don't have an idea on how to continue.

I would like to have a hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The derivative of $2x+\sin x$ is $2+\cos x>0$ . So $2x+\sin x$ is strictly increasing and it is $0$ when $x=0$. Hence it is positive on $(0,\infty)$. It follows that the infimum of the function  is $0$ (since $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)=0$). Does $f$ attain this value?

Comment: I cant use derivates but you mean that the infimum is $0$, and $f(x) > 0, \forall x \in (0,\infty)$ and because its an open interval, $f$ doesnt realy get $0$, so $f$ doesnt get a minimum at the interval?

Comment: @Alon Yes. the function is strictly positive in the domain but its limiting value at $\infty$ is $0$.

Comment: Ok thank you for your help.